# Write a mocha unit test code for the following meteor code

Tags: unit-testing, testing, meteor

I want to know how to write test code using mocha for the meteor function

```
export const physicalToLogical = (physicalStatus, planningStartDate, planningEndDate) => {

  if(physicalStatus === STATUS_PHYSICAL_CREATING) {
    return STATUS_LOGICAL_CREATING;
  } else if (physicalStatus === STATUS_PHYSICAL_OPEN) {
    const now = new Date();
    if(planningStartDate.getTime() <= now && planningEndDate.getTime() > now) {
      return STATUS_LOGICAL_OPEN_FOR_PLAN;
    } else if(planningStartDate.getTime() > now) {
      return STATUS_LOGICAL_PROSPECT;
    }
    return STATUS_LOGICAL_REVIEW;
  } else if (physicalStatus === STATUS_PHYSICAL_CLOSED) {
    return STATUS_LOGICAL_CLOSED;
  } else if (physicalStatus === STATUS_PHYSICAL_ARCHIVED) {
    return STATUS_LOGICAL_ARCHIVED;
  }
  throw new Error("Not implemented yet");
};
```

Comment: Format the code first.

Comment: What have you tried? Do you have mocha set up?

Comment: @Kraylog yes i have

Answer (score 0):

First, this function has nothing to do with Meteor.

Writing tests for such a function would involve sending different statuses to the method and expecting the different results.

Here's an example (using `chai` as the assertions library) :

```
describe('physicalToLogical', () => {
  it('should return the given status', () => {
    expect(physicalToLogical(STATUS_PHYSICAL_CREATING, null, null)).
      toEqual(STATUS_LOGICAL_CREATING);
  });

  it('should...', () => {
    ...
  });

  ...
});
```

This is one of the many simple cases you have to write for that code.
Several other tests need to be written for the cases involving dates, but the format is more or less the same.